# Inserting rows with sequential identity using Triggers

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to overcome the problem of identity gaps in my table that occur when i delete rows, where the SQL Server management studio increments not the last identity that exists in the table but the last created row identity even if it was deleted.

I'm not sure how to do this in a trigger:

1- When a row is being inserted 
2- Get the last identity that exists in the table 
3- Increment that identity by 1 
4- Set the identity of the row being inserted to the new identity in (3-) 
5- Perform the insert

Comment: step 4 is little confusing. Why always it should be new identity -3 what if no rows were deleted in table that time why you want to perform step 4

Comment: This should not cause a problem, for example, if the last identity in the table is "6" then in (3-) the identity will be "7" and in (4-) I'm going to set the identity of the row begin inserted to "7".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [**DBCC CHECKIDENT**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176057.aspx) to reset the identity to max identity value in the table

> Checks the current identity value for the specified table
>   and, if it is needed, changes the identity value. You can
>   also use DBCC CHECKIDENT to manually set a new current identity value
>   for the identity column.

### Simple Demo

```
CREATE TABLE trgtest
  (
     id   INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     NAME VARCHAR(30)
  )

INSERT INTO trgtest
VALUES     ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')

SELECT * FROM   trgtest

DELETE FROM trgtest
WHERE  NAME = 'D'

DECLARE @max_id INT

SELECT @max_id = Max(id)
FROM   trgtest

DBCC checkident(trgtest, reseed, @max_id) -- Reseting the Identity value to Max identity value in Table

INSERT INTO trgtest
VALUES      ('D')

SELECT * FROM   trgtest
```

Comment: This will not reuse gaps in the identify values.  Try your test with NAME = 'B'.  Also, consider concurrency.